# Analytic maps from lower half plane onto itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I know that the bilinear map $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R},ad−bc>0$, maps the upper half plane onto itself. But I wonder what is the map which maps lower half plane onto itself such that it is analytic and injective.Is it same as above bilnear form with different conditions on $a,b,c$ and $d?$

Comment: Or: Note that if $f:\prod^-\to\prod^-$ and $g(z)=-f(-z)$ then $f:\prod^+\to\prod^+$. So you know what $g$ is, and that gives you $f$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Möbius Transformation is a continuous automorphism of the extended complex plane $\Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$. Therefore, if $f$ maps the upper half-plane onto itself then $f$ maps also the extended real axis onto itself and the lower half-plane onto itself.

Therefore a bilinear map $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ maps the upper half-plane onto itself *if and only if* it maps the lower half-plane onto itself.

So what you are looking for are exactly the same bilinear transformations, with the same condition $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R},ad−bc>0$.

(One can also argue with the Schwarz reflection principle: If $f$ maps the extended real axis onto itself then $f(\bar z) = \overline {f(z)}$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.)

Comment: Simple and helpful answer! +1 upvoted

Comment: ;I have one more doubt,"is the form of all conformal mapping which maps first quadrant onto upper half of unit disc same as the conformal mapping which maps upper half plane onto unit disc given by $f(z)=e^{i\theta}(\frac{z-\beta}{z-\bar{\beta}})?$ where $\beta\in\mathbb{H}$ and also ,I think the map $f(z)=e^{i\theta}(\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\bar{\alpha}})?$ where $\alpha\in$ first quadrant, also works,please guide me.

Comment: @IbrahimIslam: No, a conformal mapping from the first quadrant to the upper half of the unit disk does *not* necessarily map the upper half-plane to the unit disk.

Comment: ;But I ask slightly a different question,I repeat it "**does the conformal map mapping Upper half plane onto open unit disc necessarily maps first quadrant onto upper part of open unit disc?**" If it is not true then could please provide me a counter example?

Comment: @IbrahimIslam: The answer is still “no” because you can compose $f$ with any automorphism of the unit disk. For example, replace $f$ by $-f$.

Comment: Ahh,it was my bad,.... anyways thank you so much for help!